# Screen resolution lost after restart (14.04 64bit)

Tags: drivers, display, resolution

Screen resolution setting is lost after restart, either goe's to a low default or display goe's blank and have to reboot. Have only changed from 20" to 24" acer monitor which has a higher resolution, radeon 6790 graphics cards fitted.